# How to set graphics & resolution on Frozen-Bubble?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, games

I wanted to setup a few Arcade Games on my Maverick box (for the children, you know, ... :-)). I really like Frozen Bubble but I can't set the graphics preferences, choosing the graphics tab in the game just gives me a little bumping indicator telling me it's working, but nothing happens?

How to set the resolution (maybe even fullscreen?) on this game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thx everybody!

I reinstalled the game (verion 2.2) and changed the launcher to use the command

`frozen-bubble --fullscreen` (thx Bobby!)

and the game starts in fullscreen mode and works perfectly! (It's installing quite a few graphics related libs, so my guess is, the dependencies have been fixed.)

Thw ingame graphics settings tab doesn't have any function at least for me, so I can't switch graphics mode within the game. No big deal.

So, again, thx for answers - it's working now!

cya all, 
piedro

Answer (score 4):

There does not seem to be multiple resolutions available for Frozen Bubble. Even if you use the `--fullscreen` switch, the resolution will not increase. Instead the game will be displayed in the same resolution on a black background.

At least I couldn't find a switch or method to change the resolution.

Comment: The fullscreen option works for me, but the resolution isn't any higher.

Comment: @DoR: Yes, that was exactly what I tried to say with the black border...let me rephrase that.

Comment: @Bobby, no for me there is no black border. What I meant by the same resolution is that everything is just "blown up", it fills the screen but it looks blurry.

Comment: @DoR: Oh, interesting. I've 2.2 here, maybe this behaviour was changed at some point?

Comment: @Bobby I have the same version, I don't think there is supposed to be a black background.

Comment: sry guys, but I hit the graphics settings menue button and nothing happens at all! I don't even get a submenue. I'm using frozenbubble 2.2 on maverick ... p.